# Why we use <crypt_key> from magento 1 local.xml while migration from magento 1 to magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Because if I use that **crypt_key** from magento 1 and try to migrate another database, data-migration-tool runs and start to migrate that db.

Why is this happening?

What are the reasons to use that crypt_key?

Answer (score 1):

**crypt_key** is used for encryption of sensitive information of site. eg. customer password
When you migrate data from magento 1 to magento 2, you must need to define `<crypt_key>` field in **config.xml** file.

> crypt_key convert encoded value of Magento 1 to value compatible with
>   Magento2.

when you run migrate command, magento 2 data migration tool check data validation from **Encrypt.php** file,
You can check file,

```
vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Handler/Settings/Encrypt.php
```

Inside `Handle()` function you can check $this->validate($recordToHandle); function for validate of old data for crypt_key.

```
public function validate(Record $record)
    {
        if (empty($this->cryptKey)) {
            throw new Exception("\"crypt_key\" option is not defined the configuration.");
        }

        parent::validate($record);
    }
```

**if you haven't defined crypt_key in config.xml file, data validatin throws error from above file.**

```
So using crypt_key, Magento system use crypt key with encoding mechanism to encode sensitive information of users to store in db.
```

Comment: Means when I'm using **crypt_key** of magento 1 and start to migrate another DB then decryption of sensitive information is done using that **crypt_key** whose results are not usable. Thank You.

Comment: Yes its used for this purpose.